# Web Form implementation in SDL web8 + DXA 1.6

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.6, webforms

Is there any useful links that can explain different options to achieve the Web Form implementation for a website build on SDL web8 + DXA 1.6 framework.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean exactly with "the Web Form implementation"?

Comment: Hi Rick; its for that very common feature for a website where the end user can enter his basic details (first name ; last name ; email id; address ; Enquiry etc) and then records will be stored in some non cms external database; Some CMS like sitecore do have inbuilt feature to support webforms for a website to capture records; view; generate report for all the capture records  in CMS itself. Using SDL we are looking to achieve at least we can create a webform to capture and store the user details in external business database. please suggest what should be ideal approach for this in SDL.

Comment: This is probably a good reference for you: http://hem-kant.blogspot.in/2016/10/formbuilder-module-in-dxa-CDsetting.html

Answer (score 3):

DXA 1.6 provides basic support for HTML Forms. See http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-2C331449-7CF4-4031-8080-85B3F478F700

This support includes:

- Support for managing form text (labels, validation messages) in CM
- Support for doing server-side validation and View Model mapping of form fields
- Support for preventing CSRF attacks

It does **not** include support for processing the form data. That is: you are expected to do that yourself in your implementation.

An example of HTML Form processing can be found in the Audience Manager module (see docs link above).